# Rendering fusionchartsR htmlwidgets in rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, fusioncharts, htmlwidgets

I am building a new htmlwidget package called `fusionchartsR` (https://github.com/alexym1). I tried to embed a little piece of code to my rmarkdown report however, it doesn't work and I don't know why. I tried differents strategies without any success.

## First strategy

````
---
title: "Stack overflow"
author: "John Doe"
date: "01/04/2020"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Render an htmlwidget graphic

```{r}
library(fusionchartsR)
df <- data.frame(label = c("Venezuela", "Saudi", "Canada", "Russia"), value = c(290, 260,180, 115))
fusionPlot(data = df, type = 'pie2d') %>%
  fusionTheme(theme = "fusion") 
```
````

## Second strategy

```
# Webshot and phantomjs have been previously installed.
library(webshot)
webshot::install_phantomjs()

# Then, I loaded packages and built a little piece of code
library(fusionchartsR)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(label = c("Venezuela", "Saudi", "Canada", "Russia"), value = c(290, 260,180, 115))
widget <- fusionPlot(data = df, type = 'pie2d') %>%
  fusionTheme(theme = "fusion") 

# Save a rendered widget to an HTML file
saveWidget(widget = widget, file = "Mywidget.html")

# An error appeared: `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99`

# Take a webshot
webshot(url = "Mywidget.html", file = "webshot.png")
```

The Mywidget.html can be found on your Documents folder.

How can I solve this problem ?
I will be very greatful !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using webshot, you should consider to try **webshot2** on https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2 which doesn't suffer from this issue. I have replicated your scenario with webshot2, the issue is resolved as below screenshot. See [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61479575/1953250) to the similar case.

The code:

```
# Webshot and phantomjs have been previously installed.
library(webshot2)

# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("alexym1/fusionChartsR")

# Then, I loaded packages and built a little piece of code
library(fusionchartsR)
library(htmlwidgets)

df <- data.frame(label = c("Venezuela", "Saudi", "Canada", "Russia"), value = c(290, 260,180, 115))
widget <- fusionPlot(data = df, type = 'pie2d') %>%
  fusionTheme(theme = "fusion") 

# Save a rendered widget to an HTML file
saveWidget(widget = widget, file = "Mywidget.html")

# An error appeared: `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 99`

# Take a webshot
webshot(url = "Mywidget.html", file = "webshot.png")
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: I have prepared a blog post including various details about webshot2. You can see the details from http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/export-save-r-graphs-with-webshot/